# ajax file upload to a rest api

Tags: ajax, file-upload

I have a form like below to upload a file.

```
<form id="formLicense" name="formLicense" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal" method="post" role="form">
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div id="tblUserData" >
      <div class="space-4"></div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <input type="button" value="Select License" id="licenseFileButton" name="licenseFileButton" class="btn-minier btn btn-primary"><span id="selectedFile"></span>
          <input style="display: none" type="file" name="licenseFile" id="licenseFile" size="50">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-9">
         <input type="checkbox" name="merge" value="true" class="ace "> <label class="lbl"> Merge with current license</label>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="space-4"></div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <select name="destination">
            <option value="1">path1</option>
            <option value="2">path2</option>
            <option value="3">path3</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="space-4"></div>

    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="licenseSave">Upload License</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

I have a rest api to which i should pass this 3 form elements and it will do all file upload processing.

the api looks like below.

```
Path: POST /license/install
Request content type: multipart/form-data
Response content type: application/json
Parameters (HTML form): 
licenseFile – file payload 
merge – true if uploaded license should be merged with existing one, false for overwrite
destination:
1 - Path1
2 - path2
3 - path3
```

Now on save click I should via ajax I should be able to call this rest api and post all these 3 values to api and get response in success function and display it. I am not getting how I should do this. I saw many examples on net. but all are very complex. I dont need progress bar or anything. I want some thing simple which solve my this purpose. Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: It is not possible to simply upload a file via AJAX.  There are a number of javascript libraries and library plug-ins that are available to basically hack together this functionality.

Comment: Try changing your `<button type='submit'>` to `<input type='submit'>`. This will use the built-in form handler, no `ajax` required.